# Custom HealthIndicator not invoked during startup

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I implemented a custom `HealthIndicator` for our application, which is working fine.

I noticed that when I run the application through my IDE (tested with both IntelliJ and Eclipse), the `HealthIndicator.health()` method is invoked during startup.

However, when I run the application by using the JAR file itself, the `HealthIndicator.health()` method is not invoked during startup of the application.

Why is the `HealthIndicator.health()` method not invoked during startup when I run it as a JAR file, and shouldn't it behave similarly as when running it through the IDE?

Answer (score 5):

This is actually not really a bug, but a side effect caused by your IDE. You should be aware that Actuator endpoints are not only exposed over HTTP, but also over JMX. If you take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints), you'll also see that the health endpoint is enabled by default on both HTTP and JMX.

Additionally, most IDEs, including IntelliJ and Eclipse, will enable a JMX agent when running the application through the IDE itself. This means that when the application is started, a JMX connection is made, which will in turn trigger the custom health indicator.

You can verify this quite easily, for example let's assume the following health indicator:

```java
@Bean
public HealthIndicator alwaysUpHealthIndicator() {
    return () -> {
        log.info("Indicator invoked");
        return Health.up().withDetail("Foo", "Bar").build();
    };
}
```

If you change your IntelliJ run configuration and disable **Enable JMX agent**, you'll notice that the message no longer appears in the log.

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ configuration]

Likewise, if you disable the health JMX endpoint, you'll also notice that you won't get the additional message within the logs:

```java
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=health
```

---

This means that you shouldn't rely on the `HealthIndicator` being executed during the startup of your application. If you have code that should be executed when your application is starting up, consider using an `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner` bean. For example:

```java
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner applicationRunner() {
    return args -> log.info("This will be invoked on startup");
}
```

Comment: Best answer, explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer directly the question, but it looks like there is no real question here, if its a bug - submit a bug to spring boot team. Otherwise its just a statement that I fully agree with.

> Either HelathIndicator health() method should be executed in both ways or none at all.

What you're describing sounds more like a weird bug, here is a dirty way to check what happens (remove it or course in production):

Inside the `health` method of the health indicator obtain a stack trace and print it on console. 
Analyze the stack trace and check that its not a result of some /health invocation through the HTTP (for example, maybe your IDE is configured to automatically call actuator's health upon start, who knows)

Comment: The problem is both Intellij and Eclipse , So I'm sure it's not a configuration issue.  To add more This issue for me happening with latest version's of both IDE's and other team members with some older version do not have this scenario

Comment: Aha, in this case it can be because of some kind of spring integration enabled for your IDE. for example, in IntelliJ there is a spring boot integration build it and its "endpoints" and "healthchecks" that should invoke actuator's health endpoint. I think something similar exists in eclipse as well

Comment: Bottom line, its not a bug in spring, but the IDE that invokes the /health endpoint, so I don't see any actual issue here :) WDYT?